# Can't get buddypress notifications in front-end; why do I get this error?

Tags: posts, functions, buddypress, notifications

Can someone help me with this?

This is supposed to go into functions.php:

```
function cg_current_user_notification_count() {
$notifications = bp_core_get_notifications_for_user(bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'object');
$count = !empty($notifications) ? count($notifications) : 0;

echo $count;
 }
```

In the templates where you want to show it.

```
<?php cg_current_user_notification_count(); ?>
```

Source: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/add-buddypress-notifications-to-theme

The error I am getting is as follows, though:

> fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   bp_core_get_notifications_for_user() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/functions.php:18
>   Stack trace: #0

Can someone help me with this? The function is not deprecated, so that can't be the issue...

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 
if ( !function_exists( 'bp_core_get_notifications_for_user' ) ) { 
    require_once '/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-core/deprecated/1.9.php'; 
} 
function cg_current_user_notification_count() {
    $notifications = bp_core_get_notifications_for_user(bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'object');
    $count = !empty($notifications) ? count($notifications) : 0;
```

echo $count;}